# React Router 4 match property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a `AdminNav` component that has a set of `NavLink` elements so I can style them if they are active.

The sections can also be manually opened/closed to appear less cluttered.

What I would like to do is have a bunch of sections in the nav, and have the section be open if it has a `NavLink` that is active.

**AdminNav.js**
Navigation component.  Basically a list of `NavLink`s.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { NavLink, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import _find from 'lodash/find'

import '../../css/sub-nav.css'

class AdminNav extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        // Shows 'admin/' at all times
        console.log(props.match)

        this.state = {
            sectionRoutes: [
                {
                    title: 'Cart',
                    routes: [
                        {
                            title: 'Dashboard',
                            path: '/admin',
                            exact: true
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'View Orders',
                            path: '/admin/view-orders',
                            exact: false
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Cart Settings',
                            path: '/admin/settings',
                            exact: true
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Merchant Settings',
                            path: '/admin/merchant',
                            exact: true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'Products',
                    routes: [
                        {
                            title: 'Add Product',
                            path: '/admin/product-add',
                            exact: true
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Edit Product',
                            path: '/admin/product-edit',
                            exact: true
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Add Category',
                            path: '/admin/category-add',
                            exact: true
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Edit Category',
                            path: '/admin/category-edit',
                            exact: true
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'Set Category Order',
                            path: '/admin/category-order',
                            exact: true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    title: 'User',
                    routes: [
                        {
                            title: 'Logout',
                            path: '/admin/logout',
                            exact: true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            openSections: []
        }
    }

    handleSectionClick = (sectionTitle) => {
        let titleIndex = this.state.openSections.indexOf(sectionTitle)

        if(titleIndex > -1){
            this.setState({ openSections: this.state.openSections.filter((title, i) => i !== titleIndex)})
        }else{
            this.setState({ openSections: [ ...this.state.openSections, sectionTitle ] })
        }
    }

    isSectionOpen(section){

        const currentPath = this.props.location.pathname

        // Section is open if routh path matches the current path OR section has been manually opened
        // THIS DOES NOT WORK IF section is a route that has optional params (Ex. `admin/view-orders/:id?`)
        const result =  _find(section.routes, route => currentPath === route.path) ||
                        _find(this.state.openSections, title => title === section.title)

        return result
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sub_nav">
                <div className="title">Admin Menu</div>

                {this.state.sectionRoutes.map(section =>
                    <div key={section.title} className="nav_section">
                        <div className={'section_title' + (this.isSectionOpen(section) ? ' open' : '')} onClick={(e) => this.handleSectionClick(section.title)}>{section.title}</div>
                        <div>
                            {section.routes.map(route =>
                                <NavLink key={route.title} activeClassName="active" to={route.path} exact={!!route.exact}>{route.title}</NavLink>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(AdminNav)
```

So if I go to `admin/`, the `Cart` section opens as expected.
If I go to `admin/view-orders`, the `Cart` section as expected.
However, if I go to `admin/view-orders/123` no path for the `NavLink`array matches that so the section doesn't get the `open` class added.

**adminRoutes.js**
This is just a routing file that stores all of my admin routes.  It's not fully shown here.

```
import React from 'react'

import AdminDashboard from './AdminDashboard'
import AdminLogout from './AdminLogout'
import AdminOrders from './AdminOrders'

export default [
    {
        path: "/admin",
        exact: true,
        render: (props) => (<AdminDashboard {...props} />)
    },
    {
        path: "/admin/logout",
        component: AdminLogout
    },
    {
        path: "/admin/view-orders/:id?",
        component: AdminOrders
    },
    {
        component: () => <h1 className="no-margin">Page not found</h1>
    }
]
```

**Admin.js**
The parent admin route.  This has the `AdminNav`, and will route to any of the admin child routes as described in `adminRoutes.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import AdminNav from './AdminNav'

import routes from './adminRoutes'

class Admin extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="full_body_container">
                <div className="sub_nav_wrapper">
                    <div className="hbs-container-admin-nav">
                        <AdminNav />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="content_wrapper">
                    {
                        <Switch>
                            {routes.map((route, i) => <Route key={i} {...route} />)}
                        </Switch>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Admin
```

Is there a better way to go about this?  Am I able to access the actual fully matched route from this component?  Or is this

Comment: I am not sure whether its just a typo on stackoverflow or a type in your system which could be the reason of the routes not working. You have ```admin/view-order/123``` as a URL and  ```"/admin/view-orders/:id?"``` as a route. The url is singular ```order``` and the route is configured in plural - ```view-orders```

Comment: Typo.  Updated the question.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the [children function prop of routes](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#children-func).

The `Route` component takes a function as a children (instead of React
Elements traditionnaly.
This functions is called with an object as its argument. What we are looking
for is the { match } property. If the route matches then its value will be
the classic `match` object passed by the Route, else it will be `null`.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
          <Router>
              <div className="App">
                  <header className="App-header">
                      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                      <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
                      <Link to="/other">other route</Link>
                  </header>
                  <Route path="/" exact>
                      {({ match }) => {

                          return <Message />

                      }}
                  </Route>
                  <Route path="/other">
                      {({ match, ...props }) => {

                          console.log(match, props);
                          return <Message text={match ? "this matches" : "does not match"} />

                      }}
                  </Route>

              </div>
          </Router>
      );
  }
}
```

In this example, I always render something in the 'other' router, I just test if the route is matched and update the message accordingly. You'll see that the other route never changes whether it matches or not.